# Java 8, flatten a map

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Quick question, I want to flatten the following `Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>` into a different object. The current way I m doing is my embedding a stream inside of a stream, which I don't like much, is there a way to do this in a linear manner.

```
this.ourMap.entrySet().stream()
        .flatMap(player ->
                player.getValue().entrySet().stream()
                        .map(game -> new TransformedMap("StaticID", player.getKey(), game.getKey(), game.getValue())))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: What's wrong with your current solution?

Comment: its embedded was just wondering if you could achieve the same result without actually embedding.

Comment: I don't think you could make it simpler. There are 2 distinct Map so I'm not sure how a single Stream pipeline would work.

Comment: You know this would be a lot easier to read if you just wrote it the Java 7 way.

Comment: "a different object" is too vague; be specific about the type. As it stands, this question is unlikely to be of use to others.

Answer (score 0):

Using my free [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library this would look somewhat simpler:

```
list = EntryStream.of(this.ourMap)
    .flatMapValues(games -> games.entrySet().stream())
    .mapKeyValue((player, game) -> 
                    new TransformedMap("StaticID", player, game.getKey(), game.getValue()))
    .toList();
```

Here [`EntryStream`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/javax/util/streamex/EntryStream.html) class used which extends `Stream<Map.Entry>` and provides some additional convenient methods. Internally it's transformed to something like this:

```
list = this.ourMap.entrySet().stream()
    .<Entry<String, Entry<String, Integer>>>flatMap(entry -> entry.getValue().entrySet()
         .stream().map(e -> new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(entry.getKey(), e)))
    .map(entry -> 
         new TransformedMap("StaticID", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().getKey(), entry.getValue().getValue()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```